# Variable of interface type ? what is the purpose of giving interface name as variable type?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, ethereumj, interfaces, libraries

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract staking{
    IERC20 public s_stakingToken;
    IERC20 public s_rewardsToken;

     constructor(address stakingToken, address rewardsToken){
        s_stakingToken=IERC20(stakingToken);
        s_rewardsToken=IERC20(rewardsToken);
    }
}
```

can anyone explain the working of the above code snippet?

1. why interface name is given as a variable type?  `IERC20 public s_stakingToken;`
2. how inside constructor, `IERC20(stakingToken)` will work?
3. Is `IERC20()` a constructor? as per my knowledge there is no constructor allowed in interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

in simple terms

No `IERC20` is not a constructor.

In these code snippets, you are associating `s_stakingToken` with `IERC20` functions.

When you assign the `stakingToken`  to the IERC20 of `s_stakingToken` , you can access the IERC20 functions directly from `s_stakingToken` such as name, symbol, balanceOf, transfer.

So example, when you do `s_stakingToken.name()` it will return you the name of the ERC20 token located at the `stakingToken`  address.